# Remove all 'endlines' from a .txt file that contains a numeric array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a .txt file and I need it to be reshape to be an array like (580, 580)
The text is made of many **float numbers with a space between them**.
Like:

```
0.0568596534586 0.0059062688246 0.00586258685707 0.00679323271261 0.00674094498756 [...]
```

I read it like this:

```
covsys= pd.read_csv("covcomsystematics.txt" , sep = " ", header=None).to_numpy()
```

And I usually would make it be the way I want doing this:

```
lcovsys = covsys[:,0]
covmatrixsys = np.reshape(lcovsys, (580, 580))
```

But I have a problem. The .txt is written in a way I can't do this. I got the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 336980 into shape (580,580)`. Which I found really strange, because the difference between 336980 and 580² (that should be the size of this array) is exactly 580.

I checked the .txt file and I see that time to time it have a 'end line'(a 'enter'). I think it's probably every 580 items and because of that it occurs 580 times.
I'm looking for ways to solve this problem (instead of manually doing so) and your help would be very appreciated.
I personally think that if I remove the endline this problem will be fixed. So I'm looking for ways to remove the endline from this file or ways to read it that ignores the endline.
P.S.: I need it to continue to be an **array of numbers that have a " " (space) between them**. I just need to remove the endlines.

PS2 and more info:

When I ask to print the type of lcovsys before reshaping it it tells me `numpy.ndarray`. Same for covsys.

When I ask to print the length of lcovsys before reshaping it it tells me 580 (same for covsys). However, when I try to use it directly in my code in things like

```
sigma_inv= np.linalg.inv(covsys)
```

I get the error `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`

Or I got
 `1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional` if I try to use it like

```
sigma_inv= np.linalg.inv(lcovsys)
```

That's way I'm trying to reshape it in first place. And when reshaping (covsys) I got the error that I mentioned before `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 336980 into shape (580,580)`. And if I try it with lcovsys I get `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 580 into shape (580,580)`

I provided in the comments a "sample" of my problem but smaller https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnxGhT-U8c9gw8iA6vfXNqbZqjqUkND8/view.
I can also provide the full .txt if you want to check it, since it is public data from the SCP "Union2.1" SN Ia compilation.

Comment: You could try replacing the newline characters with spaces `re.sub(r'\n', ' ', rawText)`

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a smaller data set, and show us such a data set?

Comment: @Mako212 I couldn't do that :( I got "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it would be something like this  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnxGhT-U8c9gw8iA6vfXNqbZqjqUkND8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can `strip()` the string

Comment: @12944qwerty I can't. `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'strip'`